How to use the Substrate H160 address to sign a transaction on moonbeam?
Woof and hello substrated people,
I have a special issue where I need your support. I shared an extrinsic with my community to transfer $WIFD from AH to Moonbeam, so far so good.
In this example "polkadotXcm limitedReserveTransferAssets call" extrinsic I simply entered the H160 version of our community fund wallet, with the hint to change it.
Here the AH extrinsic hex-code:
0x1f0803010100511f0300010300366962ef6c05cbb62d35238d4cdc2d35816480ce030800000204320544000700e40b5402000002043205011f00c2d401000100000000
Substrate address:
5DJ3kQk6YonCTHMcU4RbyCTPbUkL8koPB5wG7ksxoy4i8Npw
H160 address:
0x366962EF6C05CBB62d35238d4cdC2d35816480CE
The community member did not change the target EVM wallet address by accident and transfered it to the H160. Now I want to transfer the 9,192,637 xcWIFD back to him or his own EVM wallet address.
Now the question, how do I sign a transaction for the H160 address of my substrate address?
Can you help me and hereby that poor pup? Much love in advance!
